# To display data in the fields in the modal retrieved from the mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

Friends I am submitting the form on clicking the submit button and simultaneously i am displaying the just submitted data in the modal.So as soon as i hit the submit button ,the data gets submitted and a modal appears with the data just submitted.Everything is working fine with my code but the only problem that the data does not gets displayed in the modal.
Here is the code for submitting the form-

```
$("#savep").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

       formData = $('form.pform').serialize() + '&' 
        + encodeURI($(this).attr('name'))
        + '='
        + encodeURI($(this).attr('value'));

             $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "data1_post.php",
               data: formData,
               success: function(msg){
                $('input[type="text"], textarea').val('');
                 $('#entrysavedmodal').modal('show');


                },
               error: function(){
                alert("failure");
               }
           });
     });
```

Here is modal which gets displayed when i click on submit button-

```
<div id="entrysavedmodal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:1000px;">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Saved Entry</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form  class="form-horizontal savedform" id="savedform">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Date:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepreview" name="datepreview" 
           value = "<?php
                  include('db.php');
                  $sql = "SELECT `date` FROM tran ORDER BY id DESC limit 1";
                  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                  $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                  $date = $rows['date'];
                  echo $date;

                  ?>" readonly /> //this field does not show anything and none of the fields show any data.
      </div>

      <label class="control-label col-xs-2">v_no:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="v_nopreview" name="v_no"  autocomplete="off" readonly /> //same problem 
      </div>

    </div>
   </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="print"  name="print" >Print</button>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
   </form>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Date field does not show the date value from database and v_nopreview field also does not show anything.
I have tried to give as much details as possible but in case if you need anything then let me know.Please let me know why the data is not being displayed inside the input fields in modal.
Thanks in advance.
Edited part
Here is the data1_post.php code-

```
<?php
include('db.php');
$sql = "INSERT INTO `table1` (`date`, `v_no`, `name`,`narration`,`stk_y_n`)
         VALUES ( '".$_POST['date']."','".$_POST['v_no']."', '".$_POST['user']."','".$_POST['narration']."', 'No')";
 if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE){
echo "saved";
}
else
{
echo "not saved";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you expect execution of php code each time after js event. But PHP is a server-side language, it interprets only once, when you request the pages.

So your php code will load some content form DB after refreshing, then you clear input's value before displaying model and as it can't be executed again - you see empty modal.
I recommend you to return saved data from "data1_post.php" and than process it in success callback

**UPDATE**

if you want to present saved data, your php code would look like the following

```
include('db.php');

$response = ["success" => false];
$sql = "INSERT INTO `table1` (`date`, `v_no`, `name`,`narration`,`stk_y_n`)
        VALUES ( '".$_POST['date']."','".$_POST['v_no']."', '".$_POST['user']."','".$_POST['narration']."', 'No')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE){
    $sql = "SELECT `date` FROM tran ORDER BY id DESC limit 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $response = ["success" => true, "date" => $rows['date']];
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

and js

```
$("#savep").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    formData = $('form.pform').serialize() + '&'
        + encodeURI($(this).attr('name'))
        + '='
        + encodeURI($(this).attr('value'));

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "data1_post.php",
        data: formData,
        success: function(response){
            $('input[type="text"], textarea').val('');

            if (response.success) {
                $('#datepreview').val(response.date);
                $('#entrysavedmodal').modal('show');
            } else {
                alert("failure");
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("failure");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: ohk i got that i should not clear the inputs and yes if i remove the clear input part then it works absolutely fine but i want to clear te inputs from the form as well because the form is submitted ,so what do you suggest?

Comment: @payal_suthar could you please add content of data1_post.php to the question, I will write a full solution for this

Comment: i mean i have tried that returning thing and then processing the data in success callback but it didn't worked well

Comment: ohk i will make an edit to my post and add data1_post.php code

Comment: actually i want to submit the data and on submit i want to preview the data submitted.

Comment: @payal_suthar Preview? Let it be, but why do you request DB if data has not been saved yet?

Comment: then you can solve everything with js, and you need to show modal before ajax request

Comment: @payal_suthar I am ready with php solution. Just explain what exactly you whant to do. Whether it should be a preview before submit or presenting result of the submit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124013/discussion-between-payal-suthar-and-oleksandr-kaleniuk).

Comment: i want to display what has been submitted just now...I mean i want to display the data just submitted and saved in database.so i am trying to retrieve that from database and display it in the modal

Comment: hey the solution you gave above works fine first time,but second time if i try to save data it gives an alert saying failure.

Comment: It means that INSERT query fails, so it is not connected to posted solution

Comment: ofcourse it is connected because if i don't use this solution the INSERT query works fine ,everytime

Comment: In your original code you did not check value of 'msg' in your success callback. So you can't be sure that it worked well:) As I do not have your DB I can't fully test that code. Please check value of 'msg' argument in your original code

Comment: well it is giving me success msg everytime without refresh..so it is working fine with my code.

Comment: so there is no issue with the INSERT query

Comment: It's good. As I can't test that code, all I can do is ask you to do it:) So there is a DevTools in Chrome browser. You can open Network tab and then click on the button that triggers modal window. Under Network you will be able to see a response from server on each request and find out what error occurs on second request